# Conversion of XML beans to Java config annotation based - handle multiple bean output type

Tags: java, xml, spring, log4j, javabeans

I have to convert two beans in one project and in XML format into another project in @Bean format (Java config) therefore without XML.

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getContext" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>false</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="log4jContext" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="log4jInitialization"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setConfigLocation"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:project.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried to convert them in this way:

```
@Bean(name = "log4jInitialization")
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jInitialization() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jInitialization = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    log4jInitialization.setTargetClass(LogManager.class);
    log4jInitialization.setTargetMethod("getContext");
    log4jInitialization.setArguments(new Object[]{false});
    return log4jInitialization;
}

@Bean(name = "log4jContext")
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jContext(MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jInitialization) {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jContext = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    log4jContext.setTargetObject(log4jInitialization);
    log4jContext.setTargetMethod("setConfigLocation");
    log4jContext.setArguments(new Object[]{"classpath:project.properties"});
    return log4jContext;
}
```

I get the following error:
**org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: &log4jInitialization,&log4jContext**

I think the problem is that the output of the two beans is the same.

So I tried to do this, hoping to solve the problem of ambiguity:

```
@Bean(name = "log4jContext")
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jContext() {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jContext = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean log4jInitialization = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    log4jInitialization.setTargetClass(LogManager.class);
    log4jInitialization.setTargetMethod("getContext");
    log4jInitialization.setArguments(new Object[]{false});
    log4jContext.setTargetObject(log4jInitialization );
    log4jContext.setTargetMethod("setConfigLocation");
    log4jContext.setArguments(new Object[]{"classpath:application.properties"});
    return log4jContext;
}
```

The error changes and is as follows:
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(java.lang.String)**

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Just call `log4jInitialization()` instead of injecting it, or use an `@Qualifier` to specify the specific instance you want. You don't want/need the factory bean, what you should do is inject a `LogManager` as that is what you will want to use as a `targetObject` not your factory bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the reply. I tried to do as you told me but I get the error again that it cannot find the setConfigLocation method in log4j. Is there another way to configure log4j? Am I doing something wrong with these two beans?

Comment: As stated you are doing it wrong, as you are injecting the factorybean **not** the result of the factorybean.